# Suggestions on making question "more focused"

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I asked a question on [how to re-init the whole router outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045518/re-initializing-the-outet-to-recreate-any-component-in-it) to cause an ugly but badly needed hack.

It was closed with status *needs to be more focused*. I haven't got that before and I'm not exactly sure what it implies in this specific case. Intuitively, I sensed it's saying that the question is interpreted as targeting a bunch of **too** many different aspects. The remedy would be to narrow down what I'm trying to achieve.

However, I'm not sure how to narrow down *reinit outlet*. In Angular, that would be strong indication that the design is flawed, which I'm painfully aware of, hence my explanation to avoid misleading people to suspicion that the question regards a confused mind misdirected attempt to follow bad practice.

I fear I need help "focusing" the question to be easier to get resolved.

Comment: "needs to be more focused" is the old "too broad" closure reason.  You were given at least some feedback on how to improve the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound Ah, I wasn't aware it changed the name. Well, in such case, I would really need additional help making the question **more** focused. The way I see it, it's very specific and described a scenario that leaves virtually nothing to open interpretation. In fact, I'm starting to lean towards writing it up as incorrect close vote. Let's see if someone has some specific suggestions relating to the formulation in question. The general help linked to provided little value, regrettably.